# onClick event bugged when used with setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable `onClick` event for one second when user performs `onClick` event on element with id `.flipper`. Problem is when I call `TriggerOnClick()` function, it permanently disable `onClick` event.

Here is code that I am using

```
function TriggerOnClick(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".flipper").off("click", TriggerOnClick);
    }, 1000);

    $(".flipper").on("click", TriggerOnClick);
}

$(".flipper").click(TriggerOnClick);
```

Comment: setTimeout will disable *after* 1 second, not *for* one second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually turning it off after one second. And so that it can be crystal clear what's happening first, I'll put the `.off` at the top of the function:

```
function TriggerOnClick(){
    $(".flipper").off("click");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".flipper").on("click", TriggerOnClick);
    }, 1000);
}

$(".flipper").click(TriggerOnClick);
```

Comment: i tried your code but for some reason it's not working. I can still click on div before that second is passed.

Comment: We're probably turning off the wrong `handler`! Can you try the current version or add the correct handler? You probably don't want to turn off all handlers.

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is a bit backwards - you would disable immediately then bind in the timeout:

```
function TriggerOnClick(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".flipper").on("click", TriggerOnClick);
    }, 1000);
    $(".flipper").off("click");
}
```

Comment: Yeah I checked before I commented. I didn't even read the question properly enough to see that OP used it himself, just thought you had suggested it, this is awkward. /flyaway

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the `setTimeout` function in javascript has a misleading name. It acts more like `sleep()` or `delay()` from other languages in that it waits the specified amount of time before executing the function in the first argument.

I think what you want to do here is

```js
function TriggerOnClick() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".flipper").on("click",TriggerOnClick);
  }, 1000);
  $(".flipper").off("click", TriggerOnClick);
}
```

Comment: I would have to disagree with you.  The name is not misleading as it doesn't sleep or delay, it sets a timeout which will trigger later and then continues on.  A sleep or delay would pause execution whereas setTimeout does not.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight problem is that I can still click on div before that second is elapsed.

Comment: It doesn't sleep/delay, but it does prevent the passed function from executing; it just allows other lines of code to execute in the meantime.  Perhaps `delayExecution` would be a more apt name.

Comment: @user2496520 I'm not sure why that's happening.  Try changing `$('.flipper').off("click, TriggerOnClick);` to `$('.flipper').off("click");`.  I think it may be triggering the event handler, but I'm not sure.